# What is a word for "having the form of a Brussels sprout"?

Tags: single-word-requests, latin

Inspired by Dictionary.com's *Word of the Day*, "botryoidal" (adj. -having the form of a bunch of grapes), and the ongoing naming process of a product at my work which has these features: **What is a word for something with a long cylindrical shape covered in small bulbs?**

If you understand how such a word would be constructed from Brussels sprout's Latin name, without including other vegetables in its species, that would be an acceptable alternative.

Comment: Another incarnation of [single-word-requests](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/6853/148067)! Good question!

Comment: So, would the Latin for a warty green pole work for you here? :)

Comment: I couldn't resist directing you to Diana of Ephesus https://www.google.com/search?q=diana+of+ephesus&biw=1088&bih=596&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiFvK2i9t_MAhWQuB4KHRjvAIQQsAQIGw, but it would not be wise to flaunt this around at work.

Comment: @ab2: Very nice! But what's that about work? I do some work at a university, and I'm sure they have displayed these sculptures to many people there.

Comment: @Cerberus Showing these images around an office or anyplace but a Department of Classics could be construed as sexual harassment.

Comment: @ab2: Ah, surely not! Who could be harassed by monuments?

Comment: http://i-beta.crackedcdn.com/phpimages/article/3/6/4/54364.jpg?v=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the best i could do was Bruxelloidal.

This isn't a real word because not much in real life resembles a brussel sprout and if something did we would be able to describe it in a different way.

I came to this word by basically following the same steps that were used to make botryoidal. The first problem i ran into was that "botry" is a Greek stem, and there were no brussel sprouts in Greece at the time when classical Greek was spoken, I did the next best thing an got the Latin translation of brussel sprouts, "Bruxellis germinantis". In essence this translates to "German Brussles", which is what the Romans called brussel sprouts. I figured id use the root Bruxellis for the new word. The rest is simple, cut off the ablative plural "is" from Bruxellis and your left with the stem, "Bruxell". The Greek suffixs "oid" and "al" mean resembling the form of so i threw both on the end in the same fashion they threw "oidal" onto the stem "botry", and got "Bruxelloidal".

Comment: Haha nice. By the way, is it an ablative, or a locative?